# Binary search for the worst case.

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms, searching

I want to analyze binary search for the worst case, completely mathematically without any ellipses(...).

I solved out the recurrence of the binary search.
$$
T(n+1)=T(n/2)+C
$$

I've already searched many materials and books.
Many said $T(n)=T(n/2)+C$. And they solved some tree pictures or master method. And the result is $\log{n}$

Can someone solve $T(n+1)=T(n/2)+C$ without approximation or any tricks?

The code below is pseudo code.

```
BINARY_SEARCH(A, target):
left = 1
right = length(A)
while left < right
    mid = (left + right) / 2
    if A[mid] == target
        return mid
    if A[mid] < target
        left = mid + 1
    else
        right = mid - 1
return NIL
```

Thank you.

Comment: This question does not make any sense to me. What is $T$, what is $n$, what is $C$ ?

Comment: Sorry for my vague question. T is time, n is the number of array, C is just constant value. T(n) is the time finding specific value in array sized 'n'. I will upload pseudocode for better understanding.